# Why am I getting an undefined reference error here?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code.

** Array.cc **

```
#include "Array.h"

Array::Array() {}
```

**Array.h**

```
#ifndef __ARRAY__
#define __ARRAY__

struct Array {
  Array();

  auto Func();
};

#endif
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "Array.h"

int main() {
  Array array;
  array.Func();
}
```

And built with the following commands, using GCC 11.1.0 -std=c++20.

```
g++ -c -o Array.o Array.cc
ar rcs libarray.a Array.o
g++ -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ -o a.out libarray.a a.o
```

I get the following error:

```
a.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `Array::Array()'
```

Why isn't Array::Array() from libarray.a being picked up?

I tried bypassing the library and built it directly.

```
g++ -o a.out Array.o a.o
```

That solves the undefined reference problem but now I get a multiple definition error instead.

a.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Array::Func()'; Array.o:Array.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here

I guess because the function can be deduced, it needs to be inline even though it's also a template function.

Comment: As an FYI, anything with `__` is reserved in C++.

Comment: Where *is* `Array::Func` defined? I see no definition of that function anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: Humor me. In the first failure attempt change the link order to  `g++ -o a.out a.o libarray.a`

Comment: What "template function" are you referring to? Is this the real code you're trying to compile and link, ***exactly as shown***?